# Flask socket io .on('event') not handled but .on('message') works fine

Tags: flask, socket.io

I'm working on a flask app with `flask_socketio` but events are not working.

I tested with `@socketio.on('message')` and this parts work fine, but `@socketio.on('my_event')` do not work.

This is me server-side code:

```py
@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(event, data):
    emit('ping', data)
    print('received message: ' + event, data)

@socketio.on('ping')
def ping(message):
    print('event', message)
    emit('pong', message)
```

and the client-side code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='lib/socket.io.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='lib/jquery-3.4.1.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var socket;
      $(function () {
        socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
        socket.on('connect', function() {
          console.log('connected');
          socket.send('ping', {foo:'bar'});
        });
        socket.on('ping', function (data) {
          console.log('ping', data);
        });
        socket.on('pong', function (data) {
          console.log('it works!!!', data);
        });
      });
```

In server side I got this:
`received message: ping {'foo': 'bar'}` which means that the message from client are sent and intercepted by `@socketio.on('message')` but not by the `@socketio.on('ping')`

I'm missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works exactly as You described.

A fragment:

```
@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(event, data):
    emit('ping', data)
    print('received message: ' + event, data)
```

Handles one and only specific event, called `message`. That event is triggered in the client by calling `socket.send(data)`, You do not have to provide an event name when using `send()`.

Next fragment:

```
@socketio.on('ping')
def ping(message):
    print('event', message)
    emit('pong', message)
```

Handles one and only event called `ping`. To trigger such event (named event), You need to provide its name explicity, and use `emit(event_name, data)` instead of `send(data)`.

If You want to trigger also `'my_event'` event, You need to call additional `emit()`:

```
    var socket;
      $(function () {
        socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
        socket.on('connect', function() {
          console.log('connected');
          socket.send('ping', {foo:'bar'});
          socket.emit('my_event', {foo: 'bar'});
        });
        socket.on('ping', function (data) {
          console.log('ping', data);
        });
        socket.on('pong', function (data) {
          console.log('it works!!!', data);
        });
      });
```

Also, when You used `socket.send('ping', {foo:'bar'});`, infact You called message event with two arguments: `'ping'` and `{foo:'bar'}`. I think that it was not Your intention, and You only need one named event, that is: `"my_event"`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did really solved but this explain very well the situation.